# From where can a creature attempt to overcome a Scroll of Protection?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

A Scroll of Protection, when used, prevents creatures of a certain type from entering a cylinder surrounding you or affecting you in that cylinder.

> Using an action to read the scroll encloses you in a invisible barrier that extends from you to form a 5-foot-radius, 10-foot-high cylinder. For 5 minutes, this barrier prevents creatures of the specified type from entering or affecting anything within the cylinder.

Creatures of that type can try to overcome that protection:

> A creature can attempt to overcome the barrier by using an action to make a DC 15 Charisma check. On a success, the creature ceases to be affected by the barrier.

**From where can a creature attempt to overcome the barrier?**

Right next to it? Within sight? On the same plane?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Technically, anywhere**

The scroll description doesn't say, so the assumption is from anywhere. Though since the scroll is designed to stop a creature from entering the area or affecting anything within the area, any creature would have to have been made aware of it first and be in range of whatever it is they are attempting to do.

For example, a spell caster 100' away has been made aware of the protected area (perhaps by a previous failed attempt at a spell). He can now use an action to attempt to overcome that barrier, still from 100' away, and on his next turn cast another spell at someone inside.

Comment: I think the text supports this answer. I wonder if you have anything to say about the (for me, unsatisfying) flavour of a creature realising the existence of the barrier, ducking behind total cover 200 feet away, then using their action to concentrate *really hard* to overcome the barrier. That goes against versimilitude in my current estimation, that an enemy can just run away and overcome a player's prepared defense remotely.

Comment: It seems to me that the "barrier" is more of a mental effect than a physical one, as implied by the fact that it requires a Charisma check to break. I like to think of it as an effect that makes creature's minds just 'slip away' when they think about entering the area or affecting anything inside it; an effect requiring an effort of will to overcome. Rules-wise, I don't see it as a problem that a creature can do this from a distance once they know about it - they would still need to approach again in order to actually target anyone inside.

Comment: How can you "overcome the barrier" being 100 ft away?